# Android startActivity(intent) doesn't finish current activity, but runs all the code from current activity

Tags: android

I have a section of code where I want to go to another activity. After parsing these lines of code, the app doesn't close current activity but keeps executing all the onCreate() method from the current activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ExtraInformationActivity.this, 
MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Should the finish() function immediately finish current activity and go to the new activity, or the app should execute all the code from the onCreate method? How can I immediately close current activity? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid running codes after calling finish, add `return;` after `finish();`

[Read this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

> void finish () Call this **when your activity is done** and should be
>   closed.

Answer (score 4):

Calling finish() in an activity does not INSTANTLY close it, it will close it after it runs all of the lifecycle methods and whatever method you called finish() from.

So if you call finish() in onCreate, it will still call onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop and onDestroy (and all of the regular lifecycle methods).

That is how it works, and you can't change that. So you'll need to adjust your code to it.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using `startActivity()`, there is no need to use `finish()`.New activity automatically pops-up.